# Left join latest inspection date to establishments using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of establishments and I want to return a result set with the latest inspection date from the inspections table. Right now I have:

```
SELECT business_table.business_name, business_table.address, inspection_table.date
FROM business_table
LEFT JOIN inspection_table ON business_table.id = inspection_table.business_id
WHERE inspection_table.date = (
    SELECT MAX(date)
    FROM inspection_table)
```

The problem is I get only one result with the latest inspection date. I need all of the establishments returned. The query will need to be efficient because I have about 600K establishments and 3Million inspections.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you mean you want one result per establishment? This type of problem is asked frequently on Stack Overflow, you can find lots of solutions under the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you are not looking for the latest inspection date at all. You are looking for the latest inspection date **per business**.

In your solution you are still using an outer join that doesn't work. Don't do that. Either use an outer join and use it properly or use an inner join if you are fine with that.

Here is how to get the latest inspection per business with an outer join (so you also show businesses that have had no inspection, yet):

```
SELECT 
  b.business_name, 
  b.address,
  i.date,
  ...
FROM business_table b
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i
           ON  i.business_id = b.id
           AND (i.business_id, i.date) IN 
           (
             SELECT business_id, MAX(date) 
             FROM inspection_table
             GROUP BY business_id
           );
```

Same with joins:

```
SELECT 
  b.business_name, 
  b.address,
  i.date, 
  ...
FROM business_table b
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT business_id, MAX(date) AS date
  FROM inspection_table
  GROUP BY business_id
) latest ON latest.business_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i
           ON  i.business_id = latest.business_id
           AND i.date        = latest.date;
```

Comment: The first example timed out. The second example worked perfectly! BTW, how would I order that result by i.date DESC?

Comment: So typical for MySQL to fail on the first query. After all, the two queries do the same thing, so a good optimizer would execute them with about the same plan. As to ordering a query result: simply add an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an outer join. When a business record has no matching inspection record, then an empty inspection record is created an joined instead. So that outer-joined inspection record will have all columns NULL. Then you have `WHERE inspection_table.date = (...)`. This dismisses all outer-joined records again, because NULL will never match.

Use `AND` instead, to make the condition part of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT 
  b.business_name, 
  b.address,
  i.date
FROM business_table b
LEFT JOIN inspection_table i
           ON  i.business_id = b.id
           AND i.date        = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM inspection_table);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended using the following:

```
SELECT business_table.business_name AS Name, business_table.address AS Address, business_table.city AS City, business_table.state AS Province, inspection_table.rating AS Rating, inspection_table.date AS "Inspected"
FROM business_table
LEFT JOIN inspection_table ON business_table.id = inspection_table.business_id
WHERE inspection_table.date = (
    SELECT MAX(inspection_table.date)
    FROM inspection_table
    WHERE business_table.id = inspection_table.business_id)
ORDER BY inspection_table.date DESC
```